# If I use "This" in an if statement will it refer to the checked values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright It is kind of hard to word this into a question so my best bet is to ask with an example

if I have a `? :` operator like so:

`var hash = self.randomObject(d[0]) ? this : false;`

And that returned a non falsey value, and used the `this` portion would it set the var to whatever was inside `self.randomObject(d[0])` or would it simply come back as the data entered through say a function this var was in or a simple `true`

This always stumbles to me about what it does and what it refers too... So I was curious to know for future purposes. Thank you!

Comment: It's called "the `? :` operator", or the "conditional operator".

Comment: Thank you! Fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would assign `hash` to whatever value `this` has in that particular scope. It wouldn't be any of the candidates you describe.

For example:

```
 var hash;
 var a = {
     method: function() {
          hash = ("hello" === "hello") ? this : false;
     }
 }

 a.method();
 console.log(a === hash); // outputs true - hash is now equal to a
```

inside the executing function, `hash` would be assigned the `a` object, because `a` is the value of `this` in that context.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for helping me clear up my brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

Entirely depends on its scope.

If this is encased in a function like so:

```
function someFunction() {
   var hash = self.randomObject(d[0]) ? this : false;
}
```

Then hash would be equal to the function (this makes more sense when you are working with objects).

If you are not encasing this in a function, then it's scope would be set to `window`. Thus, `hash` would reference the `window` object.

Comment: `this` would always refer to the `window` unless the function is called as a method of an object, in which case `this` would refer to the object.

Comment: @JosiahKeller In ES5 strict mode, `this` would be `undefined` here unless this function was called as a method on some other object or it was called as a constructor. http://jsfiddle.net/rvrq1L93/